# Conditionally patch config attribute

Tags: configuration

I want to patch an attribute when a certain node is present.

In my concrete example below I would to change the `lowercaseUrls` attribute for the `commerce` provider, but only when the `commerce` provider node is present (otherwise Sitecore throws an error).

The example snippet:

```
<linkManager >
  <providers>
    <!-- Sitecore Commerce SXA adds commerce as default, patch it as well if it exists-->
    <add name="commerce">
       <patch:attribute name="lowercaseUrls">true</patch:attribute>
    </add>
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Is it possible to only apply the patch when a `commerce` named provider is present?

Answer (score 2):

The only which I know is to use 2 config files and a bit of hacking.

First config file must be loaded BEFORE your `commerce` link provider is defined, which unfortunately means you must put it not in the `Include` folder but ideally inside the same folder where `commerce` link provider is configured:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="commerce" type="Wrong.Type">
            </add>
        </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This config file define `commerce` link provider with `Wrong.Type` on purpose. It will allow us to remove the provider later if it's not updated with the correct settings.

The second config file must be added after the default config with `commerce` link provider, so in `Include/zzz` or any folder which works for you best:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="commerce">
                <patch:attribute name="lowercaseUrls">true</patch:attribute>
            </add>

            <add type="Wrong.Type">
                <patch:delete />
            </add>
        </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

It contains a `commerce` provider with `<patch:attribute>' for`lowercaseUrls`attribute and``element for any provider with type equal to`Wrong.Type`.

So how does it work now?

1. New provider with `name="commerce" type="Wrong.Type" lowercaseUrls="true"` attributes is defined.
2. If there is now a proper config with proper attributes for `commerce` provider, Sitecore will merge based on the `name` of the providers and will replace the `Wrong.Type` with proper type of the provider.
3. And the second custom config first sets `lowercaseUrls` url to `true` and then deletes any provider with `Wrong.Type` type. If proper config doesn't exist, provider defined in 1. will be removed. Otherwise nothing will be removed cause proper config changed type of the provider earlier.